# Tomcat is closing randomly

Tags: tomcat, hangs

We are using Tomcat 7.0.21 for production. Server is hanging randomly for last week. 
It creates files like hs_err_pid4528.log under bin folder.

There are two parts in logs.

```
JRE version: 7.0_21-b11
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [zip.dll+0x5794]  ZIP_Open+0x1690
```

and

```
Stack: [0x0000000028830000,0x0000000028930000],  sp=0x000000002892d430,  free space=1013k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [zip.dll+0x5794]  ZIP_Open+0x1690

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  java.util.zip.Deflater.deflateBytes(J[BIII)I
J  java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.finish()V
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.FlushableGZIPOutputStream.finish()V+9
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.GzipOutputFilter.end()J+26
J  org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(Lorg/apache/coyote/ActionCode;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close()V
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close()V+4
j  sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose()V+110
j  sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close()V+18
j  java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close()V+4
j  java.io.BufferedWriter.close()V+25
j  java.io.PrintWriter.close()V+21
j  com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.paintAfterVariableChanges(Lcom/vaadin/terminal/gwt/server/AbstractCommunicationManager$Request;Lcom/vaadin/terminal/gwt/server/AbstractCommunicationManager$Response;Lcom/vaadin/terminal/gwt/server/AbstractCommunicationManager$Callback;ZLjava/io/PrintWriter;Lcom/vaadin/ui/Window;Z)V+195
j  com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(Lcom/vaadin/terminal/gwt/server/AbstractCommunicationManager$Request;Lcom/vaadin/terminal/gwt/server/AbstractCommunicationManager$Response;Lcom/vaadin/terminal/gwt/server/AbstractCommunicationManager$Callback;Lcom/vaadin/ui/Window;)V+359
j  com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Lcom/vaadin/terminal/gwt/server/AbstractApplicationServlet;Lcom/vaadin/ui/Window;)V+37
j  com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+771
J  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
J  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
J  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
J  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
j  org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(Lorg/springframework/security/web/FilterInvocation;)V+87
j  org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+15
J  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
j  org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+17
J  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
j  org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+294
J  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
j  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+148
J  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
j  org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+17
J  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
j  org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+32
J  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
j  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+28
J  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
j  org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+328
J  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
J  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V
J  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
J  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V
J  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
j  org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+165
J  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+148
j  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(Ljavax/servlet/Filter;Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+5
j  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+71
J  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+780
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+278
j  org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+363
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+142
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+71
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V+196
J  org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState;
j  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketStatus;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState;+124
J  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Any Suggestions?

Thanks,
Beslan

Answer (score 1):

It appears it's possible issue with some file handling, do you have this running on a filesystem using NFS?

It looks like JVM is crashing due to issue related to native O/S.

Comment: It's works when compression is off. So it's not OS.

Comment: Well it's a JVM bug which could depend on the O/S.  However, here is an answer to your related issue from a Tomcat guru: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742785/tomcat-7-0-25-apr-jre-crash

Comment: Indeed it could be a compression bug, I've seen a couple in the past for Java, I don't know if it would be possible to use another library file. I would just upgrade Tomcat at 1st.